# R htmlTreeParse partial unwanted translation

Tags: r, parsing, proxy, language-translation

So, I'm in Italy, and playing with the 'best movie' oscar list on imdb in R. Running this code:

```
library(XML)
fileUrl <- "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?           
count=100&groups=oscar_best_picture_winners&sort=year%2Cdesc&ref_=nv_ch_osc_3"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl,useInternal=TRUE)
scores <- xpathSApply(doc,"//td[@class='title']",xmlValue)
head(scores,2)
```

Yields the following output:

```
[1] "\n    \n\n\n\n    12 anni schiavo\n    (2013)\n\n\n\n \n \n\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n\n8.2/10\nX\n \n\n\nIn the antebellum United States, Solomon Northup, a free black man from upstate New York, is abducted and sold into slavery.\n\n    Dir: Steve McQueen\n    With: Chiwetel Ejiofor, Michael K. Williams, Michael Fassbender\n\n    Biography | Drama | History\n    \n    134 mins.\n"                                                       
[2] "\n    \n\n\n\n    Argo\n    (2012)\n\n\n\n \n \n\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n\n7.8/10\nX\n \n\n\nActing under the cover of a Hollywood producer scouting a location for a science fiction film, a CIA agent launches a dangerous operation to rescue six Americans in Tehran during the U.S. hostage crisis in Iran in 1980.\n\n    Dir: Ben Affleck\n    With: Ben Affleck, Bryan Cranston, John Goodman\n\n    Drama | Thriller\n    \n    120 mins.\n"
[3] "\n    \n\n\n\n    The Artist\n    (2011)\n\n\n\n \n \n\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n\n8.0/10\nX\n \n\n\nA silent movie star meets a young dancer, but the arrival of talking pictures sends their careers in opposite directions.\n\n    Dir: Michel Hazanavicius\n    With: Jean Dujardin, Bérénice Bejo, John Goodman\n\n    Comedy | Drama | Romance\n    \n    100 mins.\n"
```

Check out the first field after the line breaks... Notice how for movie 1, the name is translated to Italian (English name is '12 Years a Slave'), and yet for movie 3 only the english is given? Fastforwarding a bit, here's a snippet further along just to give an idea (intermediate steps ommitted):

```
> head(scores.df[,1],10)
 [1] "12 anni schiavo"                  "Argo"                            
 [3] "The Artist"                       "Il discorso del re"              
 [5] "The Hurt Locker"                  "The Millionaire"                 
 [7] "Non è un paese per vecchi"        "The Departed - Il bene e il male"
 [9] "Million Dollar Baby"              "Crash: Contatto fisico"
```

I do run a web proxy, so naturally when I go to the website in Chrome it gives me all english, but even in incognito mode and Internet Explorer it gives all english, so why is it partially translating some of the titles and how do I force it to stop?

Thanks!

Comment: So the values parsed are not present in the URL you pass to the parser?

Comment: Can you add the URL to the question?

Comment: Correct, if I go to the URL I see all english names. The url was provided in fileUrl, so `http://www.imdb.com/search/title?           
count=100&groups=oscar_best_picture_winners&sort=year%2Cdesc&ref_=nv_ch_osc_3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears at though IMDB must be assuming things about your request based on the IP of the origin. It's likely that you've set up a default locale in Chrome to request `en-US` versions of pages or your proxy has a more "english" looking IP, however the file transfer mechanism of `htmlTreeParse` does not use the same mechanism to download files. I don't see any obvious way to change the headers used by the `XML` library. However here is a version that uses the `httr` library to help with the HTTP Request

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
fileUrl <- "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&groups=oscar_best_picture_winners&sort=year%2Cdesc&ref_=nv_ch_osc_3"
en<-content(GET(fileUrl, add_headers("Accept-Language"="en-US;en")))
it<-content(GET(fileUrl, add_headers("Accept-Language"="it-it;it")))
```

Now we can compare results

```
head(xpathSApply(en,"//td[@class='title']//a[1]", xmlValue))
# [1] "12 Years a Slave"    "Argo"                "The Artist"          
# [4] "The King's Speech"   "The Hurt Locker"     "Slumdog Millionaire"

head(xpathSApply(it,"//td[@class='title']//a[1]", xmlValue))
# [1] "12 anni schiavo"    "Argo"               "The Artist"         
# [4] "Il discorso del re" "The Hurt Locker"    "The Millionaire"
```

So we can see that IMDB obeys the requested language from the request header.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your example... what is `a[1]`? the head commands as you have provided them return NULL, and if I remove the `//a[1]` it returns an empty list

Comment: @AmitKohli I wrapped the URL to make it look better but if you didn't remove the white space, you would probably get that error. I've removed the space from the example. All `a[1]` means is find the first anchor tag below the title TD tag. I just used that to extract just the name. You can use whatever XPATH you want. That's not the important part.

Comment: I reinstalled XML and now I'm able to reproduce your example... it's exactly correct, thank you!